# Is exercise at night dangerous?

Tags: health-informatics

Exercise is more fun in the morning, when the air is still fresh and the hot sun is not there to sting you. But not for a few of us who have to go to work in the morning, and also not fun after just coming home at night.

Some of us have time to do sports at night because in the morning we are busy. Is nighttime sports more dangerous for the body?

Comment: Where does this notion even come from? Ask yourself how many professional and Olympic sports events are held at night.

Comment: I read it from several articles

Comment: Could you provide us with links to what you have searched so far?

Comment: @CareyGregory may be he means that exercising at night may prevent us from having a comfortable sleep. For that directions are to not exercsie two hours before sleeping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are exercising outside make sure to bring a flash light and other saftey precautions. From what I have read there are many benefits to exercing at night. [Here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/wellness/night-owls-rejoice-a-late-workout-shouldnt-hinder-your-sleep-it-could-even-help/2017/06/06/276f1098-462d-11e7-bcde-624ad94170ab_story.html?utm_term=.b5f43f86b25f) is an article from the Washington Post. And then [here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/national/health-science/what-is-the-best-time-of-day-to-exercise-its-not-when-you-think/2017/06/16/2020c3ba-51cf-11e7-be25-3a519335381c_story.html?utm_term=.ae06e1d37332) is another one which talks about research on this very subject ([Chtourou & Souissi, 2012](https://doi.org/10.1519/JSC.0b013e31825770a7)). Other research in the article includes [Schoenfeld, et al. (2014)](https://doi.org/10.1186/s12970-014-0054-7) and [Gillen, et al. (2013)](https://doi.org/10.1002/oby.20379).

(I find it ironic that they said "What is the best time of day to exercise? It’s not when you think." since it is exactly what I thought.)

**References**

Chtourou, H., & Souissi, N. (2012). The effect of training at a specific time of day: a review. *The Journal of Strength & Conditioning Research*, 26(7), 1984-2005.
DOI: [10.1519/JSC.0b013e31825770a7](https://doi.org/10.1519/JSC.0b013e31825770a7)

Gillen, J. B., Percival, M. E., Ludzki, A., Tarnopolsky, M. A., & Gibala, M. (2013). Interval training in the fed or fasted state improves body composition and muscle oxidative capacity in overweight women. Obesity, 21(11), 2249-2255.
DOI: [10.1002/oby.20379](https://doi.org/10.1002/oby.20379)

Schoenfeld, B. J., Aragon, A. A., Wilborn, C. D., Krieger, J. W., & Sonmez, G. T. (2014). Body composition changes associated with fasted versus non-fasted aerobic exercise. Journal of the International Society of Sports Nutrition, 11(1), 54.
DOI: [10.1186/s12970-014-0054-7](https://doi.org/10.1186/s12970-014-0054-7)

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). The idea of supporting your answer with references is a good one, but we are looking for sources more based in science. For some ideas on reliable sources, please check out: [What are reliable sources?](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources).

Comment: I think a little slack could be given here as within the last link in this answer there are links to research they are talking about.

Comment: @geizio - I have edited your answer to include research which was pointed to within the second Washington Post article, as it is best practice here to include some information from linked pages which help in case the site goes down or the web page is deleted by the website owner.

Comment: @Chris - While the effort is appreciated, the second study does not state that they fasted overnight, merely that they were in a fasted state. And nothing in this answer actually answers the question. It says "here are a couple safety tips, now go elsewhere to read these studies." That is not the purpose of stack sites.